# Помогите оптимизировать запрос SQL с вложенным запросом

Tags: sql, join

Подскажите пожалуйста SQL запрос чтобы получить количество первых сообщений (action = sendMess) в определенный период времени из Таблицы UserAction, желательно не использую вложенный запрос.
Например, количество пользователей отправивших **первое** сообщение после января 2019 года

| userId | dateAction | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 2018-12-05 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 111111 | 2019-01-12 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 111111 | 2019-01-11 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 111111 | 2019-01-19 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 222222 | 2019-01-07 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 222222 | 2019-03-07 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 222222 | 2020-04-29 15:16:16 | delMess |
| 333333 | 2022-01-12 15:16:16 | updMess |
| 333333 | 2022-01-12 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 777777 | 2019-01-15 15:16:16 | sendMess |
| 777777 | 2019-05-15 15:16:16 | sendMess |

Ожидаемый рез: 2
(пользователи 222222 и 777777)

Мой план действий:
к таблице UserAction из временного периода приджоинить по userId таблицу с действиями находящимися раньше начала временного периода и по идее при джоине во второй таблице появится должны null поля - это будет означать что раньше этого времени не было сообщений.

Получилось реализовать через вложенные запросы, можно ли это переделать только через джоины?

```
SELECT
    ua.action,
    ua.userId,
    ua.dateAction,
    ua2.action,
    ua2.userId,
    ua2.dateAction,
       (COUNT(ua.userId) OVER () -
        COUNT(ua2.userId) OVER ()) as count
FROM UserAction ua
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT
             ua2.action,
            ua2.userId,
            ua.dateAction
               FROM  userAction ua2
             WHERE 1
               AND ua2.action = 'sendMess'
               AND ua2.dateAction < '2019-01-03 11:49:10'
             GROUP BY ua2.userId) ua2 USING (userId)
WHERE 1
  AND ua.action = 'sendMess'
  AND ua.dateAction > '2019-01-03 11:49:10'
GROUP BY ua.userId
```

Comment: Вы сейчас разность получаете до указанной даты и после. Это несколько не вяжется с описываемыми условиями задачи. А вообще можно считать количество точно по условию, в общем случае что то вроде sum(case when dateAction < '2019-01-03 11:49:10' then 1 else 0 end) (это количество сообщений до указанной даты).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Количество пользователей отправивших первое сообщение после указанной даты*. Читаем как "Количество пользователей у которых минимальная дата сообщения больше указанной". И тогда получаем:

```
select count(1)
  from (
    select userId
      from userAction
     where action = 'sendMess'
     group by userId
    having min(dateAction) > '2019-01-03 11:49:10'
  ) x
```

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно так лучше. Но может быть возможно. еще сделать так чтобы дата определялась в основном запросе, тк она будет приходить по фильтру.

Comment: @Robokop А какая разница где находится дата ? Обычно подстановка работает по всему тексту. И нет, количество надо считать снаружи в любом случае. Одновременно и группировать по пользователю и считать количество невозможно